# Forfiles command and NitroPDF

Tags: batch-file, converters

I want to convert some text files to PDF with **[NitoPDF](https://www.gonitro.com/home-1)** with a batch file, so, with this doc : **[Using Nitro via the command line](http://support.nitropdf.com/entries/21563477-Using-Nitro-via-the-command-line)**

***My Batch file :***

```dos
@echo off
Title Conversion des fichiers de type "*.txt" vers "*.pdf" by Hackoo 2016 avec NitroPDF
Mode con cols=130 lines=15 & color 0A
Set "NitroPDF=e:\Program Files\Nitro\Pro 10\NitroPDF.exe"
set "Source=%userprofile%\Desktop\SourceFolder"
set "Destination=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Pdf"
If not exist "%Destination%" MD "%Destination%"
echo \"%NitroPDF%\" & pause
::************************************************************************
:Conversion
FORFILES /P %source% /M *.txt /C "cmd /c \"%NitroPDF%\" /cv @PATH"
pause & exit
```

So i got as error : `

> 'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal control
>   or external, operable program or batch file.

I used before this code with a normal `for` but the problem that `NitroPDF.exe` don't close after converting each file, so , i must close it manually to continue in the batch file:

```dos
@echo off
Title Conversion des fichiers de type "*.txt" vers "*.pdf" by Hackoo 2016 avec NitroPDF
Mode con cols=130 lines=15 & color 0A
Set "NitroPDF=e:\Program Files\Nitro\Pro 10\NitroPDF.exe"
set "Source=%userprofile%\Desktop\VME_TRANSFERT"
set "Destination=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Pdf"
If not exist "%Destination%" MD "%Destination%"
::************************************************************************
:Conversion
FOR %%a IN ("%source%\*.txt") DO (
    echo            Conversion du fichier "%%a" vers "%%~na.pdf" ... & echo.
    "%NitroPDF%" /cv "%%a"
    rem Taskkill /IM "NitroPDF.exe" /F
    Call :Deplacer
    cls & echo.
)
rem Taskkill /IM "NitroPDF.exe" /F
pause & exit
::************************************************************************
:Deplacer
for %%f in ("%tmp%\*.pdf") do (
    Move "%%f" "%Destination%\">nul 2>&1
)
goto:eof
::************************************************************************
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a normal `FOR` command?

Comment: @Squashman the problem when i use a normal `FOR` command the `NitoPDF.exe` don't close

Comment: Using `FORFILES` with `CMD.EXE` is a big performance hit.  Regardless, using `FOR` should not keep `NitroPDF` from closing.

Comment: @Squashman take a look on my last edit question !

Comment: When using the base `FOR` command did you ever trying executing `NitroPDF` by using `cmd /c "%NitroPDF%" /cv "%%a"` or `start "" "%NitroPDF%" /cv "%%a"`

Comment: @Squashman Yes i tried before both `cmd /c` and `start` and the **NitroPDF.exe** is still open !

Comment: Well according to their support site it will always stay open.

Comment: Is this really the whole error: `e:\program' .. is not recognized...` or are you abbreviating it?

Comment: @Squashman This the whole error ==> 'e:\Program' n?est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Comment: So the quotes are not keeping the path together regardless of escaping them or using their hex values.  Very strange. Maybe you could just temporarily add the path to the executable to the PATH variable and then just use the exe by itself without the path to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ForFiles the double quote will be seen as a special character so should be replaced by it's HEX equivalent 0x22 not escaped with a backslash.

```bat
FORFILES /P "%source%" /M *.txt /C "CMD /C START 0x220x22 0x22%NitroPDF%0x22 /cv @PATH"
```

Comment: Strange, because Dave posted a solution to this same problem using the backslash to escape the double quote. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710047/batch-cmd-file-search

Comment: I got the same error as i post before and we can ecape also with a back slash ** \** but i don't know what's my problem

Comment: Although it should make no difference I have updated the code to include the start command. Feel free to try it.

Comment: @Compo /Q for what ?? when i run it i got '/Q' n?est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes

Comment: Now it works like a charm 5/5 thank you @Compo and the problem is solved :)

Comment: @Hackoo, I am still baffled that a simple `FOR` command using `CMD /C` or `START` does not work.  I will have to test this out when I have time.  There is no logical explanation for it.

Comment: @Squashman, not sure, but perhaps this is the time where the `/S` switch of `cmd` might help: ``FORFILES /P "%source%" /M *.txt /C "cmd /S /C \"%NitroPDF%\" /cv @PATH"``...